# C++ Template specialization matches different functions with namespace op

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, overloading

I have run into a situation that looks like this. I am using g++ on Windows 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename _t>
struct test_thing {};

template<typename _t> void test_2(_t) { printf("A"); }

template<typename _t>
void test()
{
    //test_2(_t{}); // prints: ABC
    ::test_2(_t{}); // prints: ABA    <-- namespace op, searching different?
}

template<>            void test_2(double)         { printf("B"); }
template<typename _t> void test_2(test_thing<_t>) { printf("C"); }

int main()
{
    test<int>();
    test<double>();
    test<test_thing<int>>();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why/how is the namespace op changing how the compiler is searching for the function to call. Doesn't the compiler find the most specialized template function that matches the args? If `test_2(test_thing<_t>)` is defined above `test` it finds it, but only with the `::`, not below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't the compiler find the most specialized template function that matches the args?

Function templates can't be partial specialized. The last `test_2` is overloaded with the 1st one.

```
template<typename _t> void test_2(_t) { printf("A"); } // overload #1

template<typename _t>
void test()
{
    //test_2(_t{}); // prints: ABC
    ::test_2(_t{}); // prints: ABA    <-- namespace op, searching different?
}

template<>            void test_2(double)         { printf("B"); } // explicit specialization for overload#1
template<typename _t> void test_2(test_thing<_t>) { printf("C"); } // overload #2
```

Given `test_2(_t{});`, [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) helps and finds the 2nd overloaded `test_2`. For `::test_2(_t{});` ADL won't take effect, only the 1st `test_2` (and its specialization) could be found.

Comment: I see so normal overloading rules, by using the argument types to find the right function. But then those rules just don't kick in when calling into a different namespace? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Iain Compared to overloading this is a name lookup issue which happens before overloading resolution. Unqualified name lookup (like `test_2(_t{});`) and qualified name lookup (like `::test_2(_t{});`) have different rules. As the effect, the 2nd overload might be found or not. ADL makes it possible to find names from other namespaces, while you specify the calling as `::test_2(_t{});`, you specify that you want to call `test_2`  from specified namespace explicitly, then ADL won't take effect.